# How to configure httpd.conf in wamp so others can reach my webserver online

Tags: apache, webserver, wamp

I wish to set up a webpage for testing purposes on a PC with wamp (I know it is not recommended).

I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b50hB7cfsfg

But if I change the default settings in httpd.conf:

`listen 0.0.0.0:80`
to my IP:
`listen xxx.x.xxx.212`

and

`ServerName localhost:80`
to
`toServerName xxx.x.xxx.212`

and

```
<Directory />     
    AllowOverride none     
    Require all denied 
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory />
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Then restart wamp, I get the following Error:

```
There is a syntax error in Apache conf files.
AH00526: Syntax error on line 70 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.54.2/conf/httpd.conf:
Port must be specified
```

What should I do to correct this error?

I found many topic whit simmilar problems but they were outdated.
(I installed wamp 3.3.0)

Comment: RULE 1; You should never change the section `<Directory /> .....` In this case all you have actually done is change the Apache 2.4 (the newest) syntax to the OLD Apache 2.2 syntax ___NOTE___ Next version of WAMPServer will not contain the compat extension so Apache 2.2 syntax will stop working

Comment: Do you have a domain name registered in DNS?

Comment: When you follow online tutorials, you have to take most of what yo see with a pinch of salt. Never follow their instructions blindly!! Take the info they give and then go and research it in the relevant manual/documentation. **Make sure it makes sense, is accurate and you understand what it is doing**

Comment: @RiggsFolly To be pedantic, that wasn’t all that was done to the directory block. Disabling .htaccess scanning was also removed - `AllowOverride None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put back `:80` for the `listen` directive where it’s required to specify the port.

You don’t need to be specific about the IP address there. `listen 0.0.0.0:80` would work fine meaning listen on port 80 for all IP addresses.